# walking in NetLogo in evacuation model

Tags: netlogo

I am modelling an evacuation behaviour from one floor I wrote my code and there isn't any error from Netlogo, but I didn't know why my model doesn't work.

```
to go
  ask turtles with [pcolor = yellow] [walk] 
  tick
end

to walk
  ;room1
  ask turtles with [pxcor < 71 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 50]
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 58.57 and pxcor >= 49.42 and pycor = 50]] 
  ;room2
  ask turtles with [pxcor < 112 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 71 and pycor > 50]
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 108.57 and pxcor >= 99.42 and pycor = 50]] 
  ;room3
  ask turtles with [pxcor < 82 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 0]
  [face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 79.575 and pxcor >= 70.425 and pycor = 36]] 
  ;room4
  ask turtles with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 82 and pycor > 0]
  [face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 93.575 and pxcor >= 84.425 and pycor = 36]] 
  fd 0.5

  ;corridor
  ask turtles with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 50 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 36]
  [face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 132 and pxcor >= 112 and pycor = 50]] 
  ;exit
  ask turtles with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 79 and pxcor >= 112 and pycor >= 50]
  [face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 129.57 and pxcor >= 120.42 and pycor = 79]] 
  fd 1

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not particularly clear because 'doesn't work' doesn't provide enough information about the problem. To get a more useful answer, you should describe the behaviour you expect and the behaviour you actually get. Having said that, however, there's an obvious problem with your code that is probably what you are asking about.

In your go statement, you have the `turtles` call the walk procedure. In your walk procedure, you have the `face` command inside the `ask turtles` brackets, but the `fd` command outside the brackets. I am assuming that is intentional and that what you are trying to do is have the four `if` statements make the `turtle` face the direction you want and then the `fd` move it.

However, within the walk procedure you are repeating the `ask turtles`. What you probably want to do is only change the heading of one turtle (the one that is being asked to walk).

```
to go
  ask turtles with [pcolor = yellow] [walk] 
  tick
end

to walk
  ;room1
  if pxcor < 71 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 50
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 58.57 and pxcor >= 49.42 and pycor = 50]
  ] 
  ;room2
  if pxcor < 112 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 71 and pycor > 50
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 108.57 and pxcor >= 99.42 and pycor = 50]
  ] 
  ;room3
  if pxcor < 82 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 0
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 79.575 and pxcor >= 70.425 and pycor = 36]
  ] 
  ;room4
  if pxcor < 132 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 82 and pycor > 0
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 93.575 and pxcor >= 84.425 and pycor = 36]
  ] 
  fd 0.5

  ;corridor
  if pxcor < 132 and pycor < 50 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 36
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 132 and pxcor >= 112 and pycor = 50]
  ] 
  ;exit
  if pxcor < 132 and pycor < 79 and pxcor >= 112 and pycor >= 50
  [face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 129.57 and pxcor >= 120.42 and pycor = 79]
  ] 
  fd 1

end
```

There's some other issues in this code. The first is that you appear to be mixing up `xcor` and `pxcor` (and similarly for y coordinates). `xcor` is the turtle coordinate and `pxcor` is the patch coordinate. A turtle does have access to the patch's variables, including coordinates, so the code won't generate an error. But I am concerned by statements like `face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 108.57 and pxcor >= 99.42 and pycor = 50]`. This is equivalent to `face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 108 and pxcor >= 100 and pycor = 50]` because `pxcor` and `pycor` are integers. The fact that you have decimals in this is what makes me think you are confused about coordinates.

The second is that all turtles who are asked to walk are going to move forward by 1.5 but I think you want some to move 0.5 and others to move 1. Once the turtle has entered the walk procedure, the `if` statements (or the `with` in your version) only change the heading. The `fd` statements apply to all turtles.

Third, I'd be tempted to use `patch-sets` to simplify the readability of this code. Something like:

```
to go
  ask turtles with [pcolor = yellow] [walk] 
  tick
end

to walk
  let room1 patches with [pxcor < 71 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 50]
  let room2 patches with [pxcor < 112 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 71 and pycor > 50]
  let room3 patches with [pxcor < 82 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 0]
  let room4 patches with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 82 and pycor > 0]
  let corridor patches with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 50 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 36]
  let exitpoint patches with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 79 and pxcor >= 112 and pycor >= 50]

  ask turtles-on room1
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 58 and pxcor >= 50 and pycor = 50
    fd 0.5
  ]
  ask turtles-on room2
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 108 and pxcor >= 100 and pycor = 50
    fd 0.5
  ]
  ask turtles-on room3
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 79 and pxcor >= 71 and pycor = 36
    fd 0.5
  ]
  ask turtles-on room4
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 93 and pxcor >= 85 and pycor = 36
    fd 0.5
  ]

  ask turtles on corridor
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 132 and pxcor >= 112 and pycor = 50]
    fd 1
  ] 
  ask turtles-on exitpoint
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 129 and pxcor >= 121 and pycor = 79]
    fd 1
  ]

end
```

Note that this is not the same as yours because I don't know what patches are yellow. You would have to modify to deal with this issue.

The reason I moved the `ask turtles` inside the procedure was so the patch-sets are only created once. If you are going to use these rooms etc in other places, it would be worth having them as global variables and putting the construction into your setup.

Comment: @ JenB I did all changes that you said. I have a plan with 4 rooms that all open in a corridor and there is a main exit at the end of corridor. I want to exit my agents from rooms to corridors and from corridors to main exit. I have a problem that agents stay at the exit doors of rooms and they don't cross over from rooms to corridor and after all agents are in corridor, I want to navigate them to main exit. Would you please guide me.

Comment: you could also create a patch-set for all the doors and add a line `ask turtles-on doors [rt 50 lt 50 fd 0.5]` which will keep them going approximately in the same direction as they were before they got to the door.